# Setting variables from remote data in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling the function `Allow()` in html code, if returns `true`, will allow the user to Edit the data.

The functions `$scope.GetCurrentStatus()`, `$scope.GetCurrentStatus()` both are synchronous.

But it returns the following error in `Allow()` method.

```
Type Error: Cannot read property 'UserType' of undefined
```

Help me to handle the situation.

```
//LoadStatus
$scope.GetCurrentStatus = function () {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "../Documentation/Documentation.aspx/GetStatus",
        data: {}
    })
    .then(function (response) {
       defer.resolve(response.data.d);
        $scope.Status = response.data.d;
    }),
    function (error) { data, status };
}

$scope.GetCurrentStatus();

//Load AccessRole 
$scope.GetAccessRole = function () {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "../Documentation/Documentation.aspx/GetAccessRole",
        data: {}
    })
   .then(function (response) {
       defer.resolve(response.data.d);
       $scope.Access = response.data.d;
   }),
   function (error) { data, status };
};

$scope.GetAccessRole();

$scope.Allow = function () {
    if ($scope.Access.UserType == 'Admin' || !($scope.Status.Status == 'CC' || $scope.Status.Status == 'CD'))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is your function GetAccessRole() returning the data you want? Keep console.log($scope.Access) there.

Comment: How can `GetCurrentStatus` and `GetAccessRole`  are synchronous. You are using promises which made them async. By the time you are calling `Allow()`, you havent got your response.

Comment: Yes  GetAccessRole() returns data. But $scope.Allow() executed before GetAccessRole() returns data.

Answer (score 2):

Although the functions `$scope.GetCurrentStatus()` and `$scope.GetCurrentStatus()` are called in a synchronous fasion, they have some asynchronous code in them.

Unfortunately your variable `$scope.Access` and `$scope.Status` are created only inside these asynchronous methods. So, it takes some waiting for a network response until the time comes to set your scope variables.

One workaround is to declare `$scope.Access` and `$scope.Status` somewhere upper in the controller.

```
$scope.Access = {};
$scope.Status = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using `$scope.Allow` before setting actual `$scope.Access` variable set by any value due to async call.
So you can call `$scope.Allow` method inside defer success or set `$scope.access` and `$scope.status` before calling `$scope.Allow` method

```
   $scope.Access = {};
   $scope.Status = {};
   $scope.GetCurrentStatus() = function(){
       return $http.get('http://UR_URL');
   });
   $scope.GetAccessRole = function(){
       return $http.get('http://UR_URL');
   });
```

And use as

```
 $scope.GetCurrentStatus().then(function(response){
   $scope.Status = response.data.d;
 });
 $scope.GetAccessRole().then(function(response){
   $scope.Access = response.data.d;
 });
```

and then call `$scope.Allow` method